# Basic Authentication from Perl to Sharepoint using REST API is not working

Tags: perl, rest, sharepoint

```
use REST::Client;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use MIME::Base64;

my $username = 'mydomain.com\admin';
my $password = 'testpwd';

my $headers = {Accept => 'application/json', Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)};

my $client = REST::Client->new();

$client->setHost('http://55.170.145.189:2013');

$client->GET(
    '/SitePages', 
    $headers
);


print $client->responseContent();
```

I am trying to connect Sharepoint using Perl REST api but always getting **401 UNAUTHORIZED**  error. I have verified  username and password. Both are working when accessing SharePoint website through browser using same credentials.

Comment: Iirc the Rest::Client module has a built-in way to set the credentials automatically, but I can't verify right now.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem will be with `encode_base64` - if you do this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use MIME::Base64;

my $username = 'mydomain.com\admin';
my $password = 'testpwd';

my $headers = {Accept => 'application/json', 
               Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)};
print Dumper $headers;
```

What you get at output is this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Accept' => 'application/json',
          'Authorization' => 'Basic bXlkb21haW4uY29tXGFkbWluOnRlc3Rwd2Q=
'
        };
```

Your header has an errant newline in it.

So maybe try:

```
my $headers = {Accept => 'application/json', 
               Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password, '')};
```

Which sets the base64 line ending to `''`. You therefore get:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Accept' => 'application/json',
          'Authorization' => 'Basic bXlkb21haW4uY29tXGFkbWluOnRlc3Rwd2Q='
        };
```